# Do something when an os.system has an update for systemctl

Tags: python

I have code that currently looks like so:

```py
import os
os.system("journalctl -f")
```

This watches `journalctl` live and whenever journalctl updates, it is posted in stdout.

I'm curious on how I would go about doing something when this is updated, for example:

```py
import os
os.system("journalctl -f")
if if_something_new:
     do_something(text)
```

Not sure what I can use to go about this, thanks in advance!

Comment: `os.system()` is entirely the wrong tool for this. You want to check the [Stack Overflow `subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info) for some good starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the process with Popen and keep it alive by using while with readlines from stdout:

```
   import subprocess
    command = 'journalctl -f'
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True)
    while True:
        if 'something' in p.stdout.readline():
            doSomething
```

Comment: Slightly nicer/faster: Replace "infinite loop plus explicit `readline` call" with `for line in p.stdout:`, and the test becomes `if 'something' in line:`. Lets you inspect the `line` further, and the iterator protocol is almost always more efficient than repeated method calls. I'd also recommend running the command without a shell if possible, making `command = ['journalctl', '-f']` and removing the `shell=True`, since having the shell involved can obscure errors, introduce unnecessary buffering layers, etc.